# Android activity and fragment lifecycle issue?

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-lifecycle

I have the following stack trace for a crash caused by an NPE:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.daybreak.my.app/com.daybreak.my.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ViewSwitcher.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2430)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1358)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5456)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:735)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ViewSwitcher.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
   at com.daybreak.my.app.TimesFragment.onLocationChange(TimesFragment.java:446)
   at com.daybreak.my.app.MainActivity.onLocationChange(MainActivity.java:289)
   at com.daybreak.my.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:112)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6302)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2383)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1358)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5456)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:735)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
```

The way I have setup my app is as follows:

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //...
        onLocationChange(LocationManager.getSavedLocation(this)); // Manually calling onLocationChange() method
        if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) return;
            showFragment(new TimesFragment(), TimesFragment.TAG);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChange(Locatin location) {
        if (location == null) return;
        //...
        // Call attached onLocationChange() if it implements LocationChangeListener
        Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        if (f instanceof LocationChangeListener)
            ((LocationChangeListener) f).onLocationChange(location);
    }

}
```

**TimesFragment**

```
public class TimesFragment extends Fragment implements LocationChangeListener {

    private ViewSwitcher viewSwitcher;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //...
        viewSwitcher = (ViewSwitcher) view.findViewById(R.id.view_switcher);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChange(Location location) {
        this.location = location;
        viewSwitcher.setOnClickListener(null); //<-- NPE Cause here
        updateContent();
    }

}
```

**MY EXPECTATION**
From what I understand, the `Activity.onCreate()` will only be called after a fresh start or after the user navigates back to the app after the app has been killed (explicitly by the user or by memory management when other apps need memory). If this happens the fragments will also be destroyed and will need to be created, i.e., fragment's `onCreateView()` will be called. Therefore calling `onLocationChange()` from the `MainActivity.onCreate()` before attaching the fragment is safe as `findFragmentById()` within the `onLocationChange()` would not find any fragment.

**REALITY**
From the stack trace we can see that the call initiated from `MainActivity.onCreate()`. But what's puzzling for me is that at the time `onLocationChange()` is called from within `MainActivity.onCreate()`, `findFragmentById()` within the `onLocationChange()` finds the fragment in the view container and calls the fragments `onLocationChange()`. When this happens the `viewSwitcher` is `NULL` and causes the app to crash.

Obviously, fragment has already been added to the view container and the fragments `onCreateView()` has not been called yet.

**THE QUESTION**

I am not able to recreate this crash, and not sure of the lifecycle process that is causing this.

So can anyone tell me

1. how to reproduce this error and
2. the lifecycle process that is responsible for the flow that is causing the NPE?

Comment: FindViewById returns null under certain conditions, yes. I don't see why that's a lifecycle problem

Comment: You can reproduce the error quite easily by excluding `view_switcher` from the Fragment's XML layout

Comment: @cricket_007 I doubt that my users are editing the fragment's XML file... Need to know how its occurring when running on user devices.

Comment: You didn't really say anything about this being an external stacktrace of a user, you just said you have an NPE and this stacktrace, so the ViewSwitcher is null because it was never found...

Answer (score 0):

This is being caused by device rotation. Can recreate the stack trace by rotating the device.

**NOTE:** This can happen even when app's orientation is locked (as in my case); if the user is in another app in an orientation that is different than the orientation your app is locked to and they switch back to the app, the orientation lifecycle for your app will be fired.

**SOLUTION**
Add `f != null && f.isResumed()` before calling methods from the fragment. `isResumed()` will return `false` if fragment hasn't been resumed after recreation.